# What message bus technologies exist in the *nix ecosystem?

Tags: nservicebus, soa, akka, zeromq, amqp

My only experience with SOA comes from working with NServiceBus.  It's really well designed and has some nifty features that I really like:

- Processing of messages is transactional (and taken care of for you), so it's "once and only once" (as opposed to "at least once")
- Built-in saga support
- Automatic retry support
- Pub/sub support (but I assume all service/message busses support this)

All that stuff leaves me to concentrate exclusively on the app's logic, but I've only used it in .NET, and Windows is almost certainly a non-starter for the project I'm working on.  So my question is...

What service bus technologies out there exist in the *nix ecosystem (including experiences running NSB on Mono) and how do they measure up to NServiceBus running on Windows?

**Bonus:** In addition to the features above, what languages can send/receive/process messages from the bus?  Having the flexibility to write one service in language A and another in language B would be very advantageous for this project.

Comment: Pardon my indiscriminate tagging - I wanted to get as many of the options out there tagged.

Comment: Is .NET on Mono a viable option for your project?

Comment: @UdiDahan It's likely to face significant opposition. The development tooling is inferior compared to VS, plus they generally do not like strongly types, compiled language (i.e. C#).  However, I'm still interested to know how NSB on Mono compares to other options.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: The optimal situation, I think, would be to use NSB as the infrastructure but to write handlers not in C# (Ruby is what my colleagues prefer, Node would be my preference at present).  Is that even feasible?  Any plans in the works at Particular to make it possible?  It would open a lot of markets to NSB...

Comment: Have you seen RServiceBus? https://github.com/guyirvine/RServiceBus

Comment: Doesn't really look like it's ready for prime time.

Comment: @JoshKodroff what approach did you end up going with in the end?

Comment: @KarlGlennon I never implemented it, and with corefx, it looks like the decision would remain NServiceBus due to the superior programming model (esp. Sagas).

Answer (score 1):

### SonicESB / MQ

I can speak from experience with SonicESB on Linux. It's basically SonicMQ - a JMS compliant MOM - with a process mediation layer on top; that's the service bus.

#### Pros

- Itinerary-based routing; messages contain their own workflow for what services to visit
- Intra-container messaging; increases performance by routing messages within the ESB container, avoiding the broker entirely.
- Web service endpoints; ESB service may be invoked over HTTP endpoints, bridging the gap between non-Java/JMS clients and the bus.
- Good development tools in eclipse for developing and debugging esb services and processes in Java.
- Administration tools aren't bad either.

#### Cons

- Transactions don't span service boundaries (may have changed since version 7.5)
- No message retry mechanism; we rolled our own using a utility service and message parameter manipulation (may have changed in 7.5)
- Pricey; licensed by core, so expect to pay for it.

#### Client Support

In terms of what technologies can send and receive to/from SonicESB, anything Java JMS, that's for sure. Sonic also offers a library in .net/C#/VB for Windows technology, so you can send and receive messages from the bus. This was a huge plus for us since our development teams use RIA's built in C#.

You may want to check out [MuleESB](http://www.mulesoft.org/), an open source service bus.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite a while since I've seriously used NServiceBus (in fact, back then, it wasn't even called that - it was just replacement library Udi wrote, to an awful comm library we had to use on a joint project :) ) so I don't know about all NServiceBus features.

I would say, based on what I do know, that [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction) (originally developed by LinkedIn) would be a good starting point. It has relatively strong ordering guarantees, supports publish/subscribe to pools of consumers and is supportive of workflow behaviours e.g. [Samza](http://samza.incubator.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.7.0/comparisons/introduction.html) which provides a streaming framework on top of it

Also regarding the client interfaces. You can find the current list [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients)